# Running Java Eclipse returns exit code 13?

Tags: windows-8, java, eclipse

I am fairly new to java, and not very tech savvy, but I tried installing eclipse neon, version 4.6.0, on my computer. Once I got it, I ran eclipse, but after a few seconds it showed a screen with an error, exit code 13. I have the latest version of java, java 8, and I tried running eclipse with the command prompt and -vm command to specify where I am running java from.

```
eclipse.exe -vm C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
```

and I used the javaw.exe file too. Neither worked. So how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you confirm if you are running Eclipse 32 or 64? And also if your Java 32 or 64 bit? (it has to match). If that doesn't work, check this page for more possible fixes / references: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13

Answer (score 0):

This usually means you are running a 32 bit Eclipse and 64 bit Java or 64 bit Eclipse and 32 bit Java. They must both be 64 bit or both 32 bit.

In the error dialog you can see which Eclipse you have by looking for the `-arch` line. If you have:

```
-arch x86
```

you have a 32 bit Eclipse, if it is

```
-arch x86_64
```

you have a 64 bit Eclipse.

There are lots more details in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13) Stack Overflow question.